# Should I consider $2$ in $F$ when it isn't explicitly defined beforehand?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I saw this particular problem which I think is flawed but I'm not quite sure, so I'm asking it here.

The problem is from the book Linear Algebra (Friedberg et al.) :

> **Q:** Show that the vectors $(1,1,0),(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ generate $F^3$.

Presumably, $F$ is an arbitrary field and $0,1$ are the additive and multiplicative identities of $F$ (as usual).

Now, since $F$ is an arbitrary field, I cannot say that $2\in F$ without explicitly defining what it is (i.e., what the symbol 2 stands for in $F$) using the field axioms.

To solve the given problem, I tried to use the standard method of solving for $a,b,c$ in terms of $x_i$'s in the following equation :

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=a(1,1,0)+b(1,0,1)+c(0,1,1)$$

where $a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_3\in F$

This results in me getting no other solution than $a=\frac 12(x_1-x_2+x_3)~,~b=\frac 12(x_2-x_3+x_1)$ and $c=\frac 12(x_3-x_1+x_2)$.

I saw the same answer given in solution book for the exercises of this book but they haven't explicitly defined $2$ in $F$.

So, my question is whether this question is technically correct or not, because the answers depends on how one defines $2$ in $F$.

Comment: @WillJagy, I fail to see the relevance of your comment to my question. I asked whether I should consider $2\in F$ or not when it isn't explicitly defined. I'm asking whether the solutions for $a,b,c$ are in fact valid elements of $F$ or not since $2$ is not a standard element of $F$ (unlike 0 or 1).

Comment: @WillJagy, haha, I'm still a learner, you know. My username suggests that already. :D

Comment: Still, thanks for your attempt to help. :)

Comment: Yes, you should consider $2$ to be an element of $F$. Of course it may be $0$, in which case $\frac{1}{2}$ cannot be considered an element of $F$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes, that's why I asked about what to do when $2$ isn't explicitly defined (maybe the term "well-defined" is more apt here). Bottom line, if I answer the question, do I need to define $2$ as $1+1$ or is it implicitly implied?

Comment: There will not be universal agreement. If one wants to be careful, one can say I will use $2$ as an abreviation for $1+1$.